# unable to generate recorded script in gatling in CLI

Tags: command-line, performance-testing, gatling

When trying to use Gatling CLI mode, the gatling starts successfully and recording is also happening. But the problem is when stopping the recording. As mentioned by the documentation (https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/recorder/), it can be stopped either by CTRL-C or by killing the pid available in .gatling-recorder-pid file.

I have used the second approach. Though the recording is stopped successfully, it is unable to create the simulation file. After doing some trial and error the only understanding i have now is that unless CTRL-C is pressed, it can never create a simulation file and killing pid only stops the recorder just before the file creation. But i am unable to simulate the CTRL-C action in windows command prompt from java. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The kill command sends a `SIGTERM` (termination) signal. The `SIGINT` (interrupt) signal is the one equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
kill -SIGINT processPIDHere
```